# python program using dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

We represent scores of batsmen across a sequence of matches in a two level dictionary as follows:

```
   {
        'match1':{
            'player1':57, 
            'player2':38
        }, 
        'match2':{
            'player3':9, 
            'player1':42
        }, 
        'match3':{
            'player2':41, 
            'player4':63, 
            'player3':91
        }
    }
```

Each match is identified by a string, as is each player.  The scores are all integers.  The names associated with the matches are not fixed (here they are `'match1','match2','match3'`), nor are the names of the players.  A player need not have a score recorded in all matches

Define a Python function `orangecap(d)` that reads a dictionary `d` of this form and identifies the player with the highest total score.  Your function should return a pair `(playername,topscore)` where playername is a `string`, the name of the player with the highest score, and topscore is an `integer`, the total score of playername.

The input will be such that there are never any ties for highest total score.

For instance:

```
orangecap({'match1':{'player1':57, 'player2':38}, 'match2':{'player3':9, 'player1':42}, 'match3':{'player2':41, 'player4':63, 'player3':91}})
('player3', 100)

orangecap({'test1':{'Ashwin':84, 'Kohli':120}, 'test2':{'ashwin':59, 'Pujara':42}})
('Kohli', 120)
```

how to write program in python?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Step 1: learn some Python; Step 2: write this program in Python; Step 3: ??? Step N: Profit!

Comment: def orangecap(d):
  total=0
  for n in ["player1","player2","player3","player4","ashwin","kohli","pujara"]:
    for match in d.keys():
      if n in d[match].keys():
        total[n]=total[n]+d[total][n]
  return(total) . I did this much only I donot have any idea how to proceed futher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
def orangecap(match_details):
    players_data = {}
    for k, v in match_details.iteritems():
        for player_name, score in v.iteritems():
            prev_player = player_name
            if prev_player == player_name:
                score = players_data.get(player_name, 0) + score
            players_data[player_name] = score
    high_score_player = max(players_data, key=lambda i: players_data[i])
    print (str(high_score_player), players_data[high_score_player])
```

Comment: its showing error:traceback (most recent call last):\n
  File "test.py", line 48, in <module>\n
    print(orangecap(arg),end="")\n
  File "test.py", line 3, in orangecap\n
    for k, v in match_details.iteritems():\n
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: I have tried with python2.7 version its working fine in my system.
check your python version.

Comment: I am working in python3. After compiling program, I am entering this:orangecap({'match1':{'player1':57, 'player2':38}, 'match2':{'player3':9, 'player1':42}, 'match3':{'player2':41, 'player4':63, 'player3':91}}) ('player3', 100). Then its showing that error.

Comment: change iteritems() to items() everywhere as you are using python3 and try it.

Comment: thanks for your support but I am getting extra output and I do not know how to handle please help:Input
orangecap({'match1':{'player1':57, 'player2':38}, 'match2':{'player3':9, 'player1':42}, 'match3':{'player2':41, 'player4':63, 'player3':91}})
expected output:('player3', 100)
actual output:player3 100\n
None

Comment: As you are using python3 change last line as below and check
print ((str(high_score_player), players_data[high_score_player]))